# Jquery capturar focus si la primera columna está con focus

Tags: html, jquery

Intento lo siguiente, pero siempre me lanza `false`:

```
alert($('.table tr:first').is(":focus"));
```

Quiero permitir mostrar una ventana modal cuando se presiona `f2` y cualquier `td` de la primera columna está con `focus`.

```
 $(document).keydown(function(evt){         
    if (evt.keyCode==113 && $('.table tr:first').is(":focus")){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: dentro de tu table posees input algo asi: <tr><td><input type="text"></td>....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que nada funciona hasta ahora, se me ocurre un pequeño "truco". Podrías hacer que todos los 'td' de la primera columna fueran `input`,ya sea de tipo button o text y añadirles un `onkeypress`.Así:

```
<input type="button" onkeypress="tuFuncion()">
```

Así te garantizas que la función se ejecute solo cuando haya un focus en el td.

Comment: no sale la alerta.

Comment: ummm.... ahora que me fijo, ¿la tabla tiene una clase table? sino es así, el selector debería de ser ` $('table tr:first')`, sin el punto

Comment: hay una clase table que la tengo centrada y con un ancho del 80%

Comment: He cambiado por completo la respuesta por si le quieres echar un vistazo.

Comment: cree esta funcion function muestraModal(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode==113){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
} pero no funciona, llamo la funcion desde el onkeypress del input así onkeypress="muestraModal(event)"

Comment: solucionado utilicé onkeydown

Answer (score 0):

Como te habían comentado puedes realizar desde el propio evento **onkeyup** del **input**:

```js
function miFuncion(sender){
 alert('Valor del input: '+sender.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="miTabla">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="1" onkeyup="miFuncion(this);"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2" onkeyup="miFuncion(this);"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3" onkeyup="miFuncion(this);"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="6"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Espero te sirva..!!